# How can I get the format of an image?

Tags: android

I have an image in my drawable folder and I want to know which format it is. How can I do this?

Comment: The drawable folder is defined at design time and cannot be changed in the run time. The only files there are the ones you put in. How come you don't know the format of your own files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this. As i know all drawables are "precomplied" and there are no info about initial drawable type.

Why are you bothering about format?

Comment: I want to know whether the image is JPEG OR PNG etc.

Answer (score 0):

Load into a Drawable object and analyse the run-time class of the Drawable.

```
Drawable d = Ctxt.getDrawable(R.drawable.nnn);
if(d instanceof BitmapDrawable)
   //...
else if(d instanceof NinePatchDrawable)
  //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
I want to know whether the image is JPEG OR PNG etc.

Comment: Why would you want that? Android abstracts the format away from you anyway. You don't (should not) work with those images as files - you load them as drawable resources.